# How to adjust Excel columns count to project into DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to fetch data from Excel sheet and fill data into an DataTable in c# by using EPPlus by this code:

```
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
using(var _excel = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fileAddress)){ 
var data = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells.ToDataTable(options =>
            {
                options.FirstRowIsColumnNames = true;
                options.EmptyRowStrategy = EmptyRowsStrategy.StopAtFirst;
            });
}
```

but when I am running this code I am getting this error:

> first row contains an empty cell at index 4

which 4 is the index of the first empty cell after data ends.
I try to set column mapping but no progress has been made. is there any way to determine the table dimension to cast to DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

Add Nuget package of ClosedXML to the solution.

```cs
using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

call this function when you want in your code:

```
string strFileName = @"C:\VSTSInput\InputFileVSTS_File1.xlsx";
string strSheetName = "Sheet 1";
DataTable DT_InputData = GetDataFromExcel(strFileName, strSheetName);
```

Create the following as a method, to reuse it:

```
    public static DataTable GetDataFromExcel(string path, dynamic worksheet)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(path))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(worksheet);

            //Create a new DataTable.

            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(1, dt.Columns.Count))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            toInsert[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Failed at: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(toInsert);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Your data from the excel will be added to the DataTable and you can access the columns by the following code:

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in DT_InputData.Rows)
{
    var dataColumn1 = dtRow[0].ToString(); //Data of 1st column in excel
    var dataColumn2 = dtRow[1].ToString(); //Data of 2nd column in excel
    var dataColumn3 = dtRow["Your Excel Column Name"].ToString();
}
```